# How can I call phones from my pc using a mobile phone connected to my pc?

Tags: linux, mobile-phone, at, call

I mean this question in abstract for usb/bluetooth connected featurephones and dumbphones.
But also specially for this mobile phone:

Motorola RAZR V3i

I have computers running debian and ubuntu, can connect my phone via usb and/or bluetooth over AT.
I tried every phone management software out of the repositories, but they only seem to manage SMS and PIM functions like contacts, calendar.
Is there any software that can start and listen for (voice) calls using the phones line and the computers audio system?

UPDATE Still no luck but another question related.